# Numpy repeat to odd length index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe:

```
proj_length = 6
nb_date = pd.Period("2017-10-13")
rb_date = pd.Period("2017-11-13")

rev_length = proj_length * 30
end_date = rb_date + (rev_length * 2)

df_index = pd.PeriodIndex(start=nb_date, end=end_date)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0,0]] * len(df_index),
                  index=df_index,
                  columns=["in", "out"])
len(df) == 392
```

And i'm trying to groupby 30 days at a time, so my initial thought was to just create some new column:

```
groups = (end_date - nb_date) // 30
gb_key = np.repeat(np.arange(groups), 30)
len(gb_key) == 390
```

This is good so far, but I cannot figure out a pythonic way to get the overflow (392-390) to be set to `13`?

Non-numpy/pandas way:

```
arr = np.zeros(len(df))
for i, idx in enumerate(range(0, len(df), 30)):
    arr[idx:] = i
```

Comment: `proj_length = ???`

Comment: Edited, but it's 6 for testing, hopefully variable.

Comment: `np.arange(len(df))//30`?

Comment: @Divakar Feeling a little silly with my answer after seeing that ^.

Comment: Whoops, of course... overlooking the simple math.